# nginx SSI call - how to execute a script via proxy pass?

Tags: nginx, ssi

I'm trying to work out how to get this going in my HTML page:

```
<!--# exec cgi="/cgi-bin/links/track_ssi.cgi" -->
```

I see this in the log file:

```
invalid SSI command: "exec" while sending response to client
```

We have a proxy pass from nginx to Apache2.4:

```
    location ~ \.cgi$ {
        gzip off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
    }
```

As far as I can see though, its not even getting that far. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `exec cgi` SSI command, please see [Nginx documentation on SSI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#commands).

Correct SSI fragment will be

```
<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/links/track_ssi.cgi" -->
```

(assuming everything else is correctly configured)

Comment: Thanks - that got rid of the error, but it leads onto another problem. Before we used this to get the page in question: `$ENV{DOCUMENT_URI} =~ /Detailed\/(\d+)\.html/ and $link_id = $1;`, but `$ENV{DOCUMENT_URI}` doesn't seem to be passed along - is there a way to pass the current URL along in the request?

Comment: Scrap that - worked out I can just pass in `<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/links/track_ssi.cgi?link=21" -->`, and it works like a charm. Thanks! (it won't let me give you the bounty for 23 hours though :/)